# relative path in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have included a web editor project in asset folder of android app, it has some html and css files in its folders, if i open them in browser , it works fine if i load it in android webview, its relative paths dont work

I have loaded my first page using

```
webView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html","utf-8");
```

where htmlString is actually the html file in String form using BufferedReader

relative paths are given like

```
href="index.html"
```

if file is in same folder and like

```
src="../../../js/jquery.min.js"
```

if file is in other folder

Comment: Try with href="file:///android_asset/index.html". I didn't used but may work..

Comment: hey, thanks a lot buddy , i tried this way earlier in java code, but never used it in html, but using it in html actually worked, thanks a lot, it solved my problem

Comment: @Pankaj... You probably should add your comment as an answer... and let it be marked as the correct answer.